# Remove Part of a Folder Name in Bulk, (similar to find and replace?)

Tags: batch-file

Apologies in advance.  I researched several of the similar questions and tried to use the scripts or shell commands offered, but they didn't work for my particular issue.  I think it's because most of the other questions dealt with exact locations in the Folder name, or with removing a series of numbers and the like.

One of the other things that I was having trouble understanding in the previous batch files and shell commands offered, is that they didn't specify how to include a specific directory.  (they may be assuming that the users already know where to put that.  I'm really new, so I'm not sure.  Attempts to do so using lines from previous batch files has not worked).

I have several thousand folders where I want to remove part of the folder name (if only windows would do a find and replace for folder names, because that's basically what I want to do, find each of the text strings I want OUT and replace them with blank).

The folders all have unique names, but the portion of the name I want to remove is basically the same.  And I don't want any of the files within the name to be affected in any way.  ONLY the folder names.

For example:

- 12345_A_9101112_Method_Names
- 12355_393939_Method_NameB33
- 12366_BC_1234_Method_Name

What I want to remove from the folder name is the text string represented in my example by "Name...".  On a few of them, I believe that that part is one or two underscores in the name, rather than at the end.  And there are approximately 8 different text strings I want removed (I'm guessing I'll have to have a different batch file for each different name?).

As you can see, the folder names vary somewhat, they're not all the same length and naming convention up to the part to be removed.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: There are a few batch file renamers that are both free and capable of using regular expressions to do what you need.  Just search google for batch file renamer

Comment: Thanks Miltox, Unfortunately we're restricted from downloading any third party software (where I work, it almost literally takes an act of congress to allow anything).  This is why I have to write these darned things myself.  I'm gradually learning, and plan on picking up a textbook this weekend.  But for now, was hoping for a semi-"easy" script.  :)

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR %%q IN (name eman) DO (
 FOR /r "%sourcedir%" /d %%a IN (*%%q*) DO (
  SET "dname=%%~nxa"
  SET "dname=!dname:%%q=!"
  IF NOT "%%~nxa"=="!dname!" ECHO(REN "%%a" "!dname!"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

This should work - you would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances. As it stands, it will delete the substrings `name` and `eman` - just add the extra required strings into the list in the obvious area.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the directories.